Optimal control and convexity
I consider an optimal control problem using the Bolza formulation : the state and control variable are respectively $x(t)\in X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ $u(t)\in\mathbb{R}^m$ for $t\in[t_0,T]$ where $X$ and $U$ are assumed to be compact. The dynamics is given by
$$
\dot{x}(t)=f(x(t),u(t))
$$
and the optimal control problem is
$$
\inf_{u\in\mathcal{U}}\left\{\int_{t_0}^{T}L(x(t),u(t))dt + G(x(T))\right\}
$$
where $f,L$ and $G$ are assumed to be polynomial functions.
I would like to prove or disprove that
$$
J(x)=\inf\left\{ L(x,u) : u\in U, \dot{x} = f(x,u) \right\}
$$
is locally bounded and convex.
Here is my attempt : working with a polynomial function defined on compact set, $J$ is locally bounded since $L$ is.
Now for the convexity, I do not know how to proceed. I know that the infimum of a convex function is also convex but here there is no convexity assumptions on $L(x,.)$ so I am tempted to say that it is false, but unable to provide an
example.
If you have some hints to provide I will be happy to read them please.
Thank you a lot !

Can I have your feedback on my answer?

@Amir Sorry for the delay I just comment your answer !

As $f$ is a bivariate polynomial, the feasible space of the problem is not generally convex, that is,
$$
\alpha\dot{x_1}(t)+(1-\alpha)\dot{x_2}(t)= f(\alpha x_1(t)+(1-\alpha) x_2(t),\alpha u_1(t)+(1-\alpha) u_2(t))
$$
does not hold for any two feasible pairs $x_1(t),u_1(t)$ and $x_2(t),u_2(t)$, and any $\alpha\in (0,1)$.
The feasible space can be convex if $f$ is an affine function.
Moreover, your following statement:

Now for the convexity, I do not know how to proceed. I know that the infimum of a convex function is also convex but here there is no convexity assumptions on $L(x,.)$ so I am tempted to say that it is false, but unable to provide an
example.

is not accurate. In fact, we have

if $g(x,y)$ is jointly convex in $(x,y)$, then $\inf_{y}g(x,y)$ is convex in $x$.

Hence, we can prove the following result:

If $X,U$ are convex sets, $L$ is a convex bivariate polynomial on $X×U$, such as $x^2+u^2+u+(x+u)^4$ for $X×U=\mathbb R ^2$, and $f$ is affine, then $J(x)$ is a convex function.

Hope, it is helpful.

Thank you for your answer ! This solves my question. In fact I thought that I should be able to have that such infinimum function is convex without assuming the initial polynomial is convex or the set to be convex, it seems that your answer shows me that I was wrong . Thank you !

@coboy You are welcome!
